# Constrained optimization - second order sufficient optimality condition

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have the following prbolem

$$
min \space (x_1-1)^2+x_2^2\\
s.t. \space x_1-\lambda^{-1}x_2^2\leq0
$$

Furthermore, it holds $$\lambda\in\mathbb{R}\backslash \{0\}$$

How do I show under which conditions on $\lambda$ do the second-order sufficient optimality conditions
for constrained optimization problems hold at $x^*=(0,0)^T$? I already know that LICQ holds in $x^*$ and that it is a KKT point.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for showing your work. For KKT conditions to be sufficient, we just need both the objective and constraints to be convex. Well the objective is clearly convex.

Constraint is convex only if $\lambda<0$. Can you argue why?

**Hint 1:** For $\lambda<0$, $\ g(x)=x_1-\lambda^{-1} x_2^2$ is a convex function and $g(x)\leq 0$ is just a sub-level set. For $\lambda>0$, let $S=\{x: g(x) \leq 0\}$. Does $(1, \sqrt{\lambda}) \in S$, $\ (1, -\sqrt{\lambda}) \in S$? What about $(1, 0)$?

**Hint 2:** $f(x) = (x_1-1)^2 + x_2^2$ Lets look at the Hessian:
$$\
H= \begin{bmatrix}2 & 0\\0 & 2\end{bmatrix}
$$
Clearly, Hessian is Positive Definite.

Comment: Thank your for your reply. I am a bit confused. So the second-order sufficient optimality conditions for constrained problems hold for $\lambda<0$ at the corresponding point?

Comment: In the question you have mentioned that $x^*=(0, 0)$ is a KKT point. Hence, I assumed that KKT conditions are satisfied at $x^*$.

Comment: Hmm, the hint does not help me. Yes, KKT is satisfied at $x^*$, that is correct.

Comment: Okay, I now understand that the hessian of the objective is positive definite and hence convex

Comment: @Cruiser2000 I have added Hint 2 to show that objective is convex. You can follow the same thing and show for $\lambda<0, g(x)$ is convex.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. That helped me.

Comment: @Cruiser2000 You suddenly rejected the answer. Is there any bug in the answer?